# Asp.net MVC integration with Okta - Issue Okta Claims replaced after SigninManager.SignIn

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, okta

I am trying to implement Okta integration with Existing application.
Current Application - it has login screen and user gets authenticated and signed in using SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync method.

NEW - I am using Okta login page. My StartUp file has below code :

```
public partial class Startup
    {
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationUserManager>());
app.CreatePerOwinContext(() => DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ApplicationRoleManager>());

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

// app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

 app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
{
    OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
    RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
    GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
    Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access" },
    AuthorizationServerId = string.Empty
});
}
}
```

My Redirect Uri is : https://localhost:port/Account/Login

Account Controller Code:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
        private readonly ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

        public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login()
        {
            if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var properties = new AuthenticationProperties();
                properties.RedirectUri = "/Account/Login";
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);
                return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
            }

            var userClaims = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims;
            //Fetching values before Sign IN as they are getting lost, adding as custom claim when receive success status
            var accesstoken = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "access_token");
            var idtoken = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id_token");
            var refreshtoken = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "refresh_token");
            var expiresat = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "exp");
            var issuedat = userClaims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "iat");

            //SignInManager
            //Not getting below information after using ExternalCookie so commenting
            //ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            //Get Custom ExternalloginInfo
            ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
            ExternalLoginInfo externalInfo = new ExternalLoginInfo();

            externalInfo.DefaultUserName = externalLogin.DefaultUserName;
            externalInfo.Email = externalLogin.Email;
            externalInfo.Login = externalLogin.LoginInfo;
            externalInfo.ExternalIdentity = externalLogin.ExternalIdentity;

            var result = await _signInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(externalInfo, isPersistent: false);
            switch (result)
            {
```

When I put a debug point to Switch, User.Identity does not have Okta Claims, it has only AspNet.Identity Claims with UserId,Email, SecurityStamp values.
When I get SigninStatus as Success, I manually add accesstoken, idtoken,etc claims in AspNetUserClaims Table and then Signs user in again to get updated Identity.
And When it gives Failure status then I CreateExternal User and Use AddLoginAsync method to map Sub with AspNetUsers table UserId value.

Is this the right way? Also I am not getting ExternalLoginInfo even after adding ExternalCookie, so manually making the ExternalLoginInfo object.

After Changes

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
            public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
            {
                if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    return new ChallengeResult("OpenIdConnect", Url.Action("ExtLoginCallback", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
                }
                return RedirectToAction(returnUrl?? "{Controller}/{Action}");  //verify this       
            }

            [AllowAnonymous]
            public async Task<ActionResult> ExtLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
            {
                var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

                if (loginInfo == null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login");
                }
                if (loginInfo.Email == null)//Email is coming null from loginInfo
                {
                    loginInfo.Email = loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email").Value;
                }
                var user = await this._userManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
                if (user == null)
                {
                    //Create User 
                }
    //Add Okta provided Claims here
                var idTokenClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "id_token");
                if (idTokenClaim != null)
                {
                    _userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, new Claim(idTokenClaim.ClaimType, idTokenClaim.ClaimValue));
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("id_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id_token").Value));
                }
                else
                {
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("id_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "id_token").Value));
                }
                var accessTokenClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "access_token");
                if (accessTokenClaim != null)
                {
                    _userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, new Claim(accessTokenClaim.ClaimType, accessTokenClaim.ClaimValue));
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("access_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "access_token").Value));
                }
                else
                {
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("access_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "access_token").Value));
                }
                var refreshTokenClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "refresh_token");
                if (refreshTokenClaim != null)
                {
                    _userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, new Claim(refreshTokenClaim.ClaimType, refreshTokenClaim.ClaimValue));
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("refresh_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "refresh_token").Value));
                }
                else
                {
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("refresh_token", loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "refresh_token").Value));
                }
                var expClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "exp");
                if (expClaim != null)
                {
                    _userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, new Claim(expClaim.ClaimType, expClaim.ClaimValue));
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("exp", GetClaimsDateTime(Convert.ToInt64(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "exp").Value))));
                }
                else
                {
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("exp", GetClaimsDateTime(Convert.ToInt64(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "exp").Value))));
                }
                var iatClaim = user.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ClaimType == "iat");
                if (iatClaim != null)
                {
                    _userManager.RemoveClaim(user.Id, new Claim(iatClaim.ClaimType, iatClaim.ClaimValue));
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("iat", GetClaimsDateTime(Convert.ToInt64(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "iat").Value))));
                }
                else
                {
                    _userManager.AddClaim(user.Id, new Claim("iat", GetClaimsDateTime(Convert.ToInt64(loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "iat").Value))));
                }
    //Sign the User with additional claims
                result = await _signInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: true);
if(result == SignInStatus.Success){
                return RedirectToAction(returnUrl ?? "{Controller}/{Action}");
}
```

//Authorize Filter used to get Active AccessToken from Okta
//Created Custom Filter to use as Authorize filter on all controllers

```
public class CustomAuthAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            //Get New Accesstoken before it expires
             if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var _oktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"];
                var _redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"];
                var _clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"];
                var _clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"];
                var _refreshToken = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserRefreshToken();
                var _issuedat = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserIat();
                var _expiresat = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserExp();
                var expire = 3600;
                 if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(_issuedat)).TotalSeconds >= (expire - 3540))//Testing for 1 min
                {
                    var client = new RestClient(_oktaDomain + "/oauth2/v1/token");
                    client.Timeout = -1;
                    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    request.AddParameter("client_id", _clientId);
                    request.AddParameter("client_secret", _clientSecret);
                    request.AddParameter("grant_type", "refresh_token");
                    request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", _redirectUri);
                    request.AddParameter("scope", "openid profile email offline_access");
                    request.AddParameter("refresh_token", _refreshToken);
                    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                    //Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                    dynamic jsonResponse = null;
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) { 
                    jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
                    }
                    if (jsonResponse.error == null)
                    {
                        //find common place to keep below
                        ClaimsPrincipal cp = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User;
                        foreach (var uidentity in cp.Identities)
                        {
                            var idTokenClaim = uidentity.FindFirst("id_token");
                            if (idTokenClaim != null)
                            {
                                uidentity.RemoveClaim(idTokenClaim);
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", jsonResponse.id_token.Value));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", jsonResponse.id_token.Value));
                            }
                            var accessTokenClaim = uidentity.FindFirst("access_token");
                            if (accessTokenClaim != null)
                            {
                                uidentity.RemoveClaim(accessTokenClaim);
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", jsonResponse.access_token.Value));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", jsonResponse.access_token.Value));
                            }
                            var refreshTokenClaim = uidentity.FindFirst("refresh_token");
                            if (refreshTokenClaim != null)
                            {
                                uidentity.RemoveClaim(refreshTokenClaim);
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", jsonResponse.refresh_token.Value));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", jsonResponse.refresh_token.Value));
                            }
                            var expClaim = uidentity.FindFirst("exp");
                            if (expClaim != null)
                            {
                                uidentity.RemoveClaim(expClaim);
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("exp", DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(jsonResponse.expires_in)).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("exp", DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(jsonResponse.expires_in)).ToLocalTime().ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)));
                            }
                            var iatClaim = uidentity.FindFirst("iat");
                            if (iatClaim != null)
                            {
                                uidentity.RemoveClaim(iatClaim);
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("iat", DateTime.UtcNow.ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                uidentity.AddClaim(new Claim("iat", DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()));
                            }
                            //This will only add claims to Identity, Find a way to save in DB as well
                            HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(uidentity);
                        }                        
                    }           
        }
```

LogOut: On Logout button click, Logout is called, and PostLogoutRedirectUri is set to Account/LogOff. But after setting RedirectUri to Authorization-code/callback, logout is becoming infinite loop of Logout, Authorize Endpoint, Callback. What I am doing wrong here?

```
public void Logout()
        {
            if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                    DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie,
                    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,                                     
                    OktaDefaults.MvcAuthenticationType);  
            }
        }
 public ActionResult LogOff()
        {
```

//Login action is called after authorization-code/callback as it is set to default rout
               return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }

Comment: Why are you not using the default callback route provided by Okta itself? Something like `https://localhost:port/authorization-code/callback`

Comment: I do not have any login button on my app as per okta samples, When user will hit my website url it will directly take to okta login page. So I had an understanding that this might not work.

Comment: That's not true. You can use SP initiated flow with Okta login page. I'll try to compile a sample and post in answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `startup.cs`

```
app.UseOktaMvc(new OktaMvcOptions()
{
    OktaDomain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:OktaDomain"],
    ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientId"],
    ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:ClientSecret"],
    RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:RedirectUri"],
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["okta:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
    Scope = new List<string> { "openid", "profile", "email", "offline_access" },
});
```

In your `web.config` make sure you have redirect uri as below

```
<add key="okta:RedirectUri" value="https://localhost:{port}/authorization-code/callback" />
```

You should not write controller for this route. This is provided by the Okta.AspNet package already. The sign in process is handled by this route itself unless you want to do something out of the box.

Your default route's action should look something like:

```
if (!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Now, you should be able to read all the userclaims in your application.

```
var claims = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.User.Claims.ToList();
```

You can also decorate your controllers/action by `[Authorize]` attribute to secure them from unauthenticated access.

Comment: This does not change anything. I was able to get Okta Claims earlier as well. My ExternalLoginInfo is still null when tried with ExternalLoginInfo loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

Comment: Also I have another question, From Okta NameIdentifier Claim has "Sub" claim value. But when I use Signinmanager.SignIn(user,false,false) after adding Access token, id token, refresh token to AspNetUserClaims table using usermanager.addclaim. User.Identity claimidentifier value gets replaced by UserId column value of AspNetUser. I am able to view my additional claims in identity, but Not sure how IsAuthenticated flag will work after this. Will it work based on okta authentication or AspNet.Identity authentication?

Comment: I have added CustomAuth Filter on Controllers where it checks for accesstoken expiry and gets new access token using refreshtoken, to keep okta session active. But as I am new to this, so could not understand it fully.

Comment: You are creating identity user and signing in which is obviously overwrite the username. The IsAuthenticated flag should work once you sign in the identity using OWIN middleware. Can you summarize what actually are you trying to achieve and where is the problem? I am getting little confused.

Comment: Existing App has custom login page that uses PasswordSignInAsync method to Sign user in. I have to remove that login and use Okta login instead. But has to maintain existing users as it is, so once okta integration is complete, users should not get impacted and can use roles etc as it is.

Comment: I am considering okta login as external login here,as i could not find any way to map Sub with UserID (AspNetUsers) and adding token to DB to use it at later stage to access few API calls.

Comment: I have added new code under After Changes Line, please see my post

Comment: In that case, I will suggest you to save your application username in the okta profile (you can use custom attribute and map that to username of your OIDC application in Okta). The username will be sent as `preferred_username` claim which you can read from user claims, validate in your database and sign in using the identity user. This will enable you to have control over all the roles and authorization part in you application.

Comment: I have saved emailid as username in DB. And Finding user based on email received in logininfo. Also I have added snippet from Authorize filter, is this way correct to get fresh tokens?

Comment: You don't have to refresh the id_token on every request. Your `CustomAuthAttribute` will send a post request every time, this will hamper the performance of your app as well as Okta will not permit this as they have API rate limits for each Okta tenant. Instead of relying on the id_token expiration, you can simply set timeout for you application and remove  `CustomAuthAttribute`. `app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions{ ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) });`

Comment: Token Expiry is set to 1 hour, for testing using it 1 min. Post call will be made once in 60 mins in Production Environment. And setting ExpireTimeSpan will internally call Okta for authentication? As i do not want user to log in every 30 mins.

Comment: ExpireTimeSpan I have mentioned is the maximum period for inactivity. User will not be logged out if they have any activity within that timespan

Comment: thanks a lot @rabink Mostly everything is working except logout, I have added my logout code as well. Please see if I have to make LogOff name to PostLogout as well, as per okta provided sample.

Comment: You should remove the `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie` from logout and it should work fine.

Comment: Removed, and got Okta login screen. But when I login it is going in loop again with authorize, callback and logoff. Do i have to update my postlogoutredirectUri as well? It is "http://localhost:{port}/account/logoff". As mentioned earlier, I am redirecting to Login action in Logoff, is that correct? Before making authorozation-code/callback as redirecturi it was working.

Comment: If you want to land the user back to your application after logout, you should handle this in your application. Probably something wrong with your redirect URI and logout URI configurations.